# react native maps not showing more than one marker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

Hi I'm using react native maps https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps and for some weird reason is not showing more than one marker at a time. What wrong with this? It's showing only the first marker.I haven't try mapping an array of coordinates but in the end the mapping will do the same as this code.

I have initialized all LATITUDE AND LATITUDE DELTA and so on.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showsUserLocation={ true }
            showsMyLocationButton={ true }
            followsUserLocation={true}
            customMapStyle={MapStyle}
            region={{
              latitude: LATITUDE,
              longitude: LONGITUDE,
              latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
              longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            }}>
            <MapView.Marker
              coordinate={{
                latitude: 30.7432680, 
                longitude: -90.3718372
              }}
              key={12313}
              title={"title"}
              />
            <MapView.Marker
              coordinate={{
                latitude: 30.7432697, 
                longitude: -90.3718363
              }}
              key={12314}
              title={"Another"}
              />
            </MapView>

        </View>

    );
  }
```

Comment: I think your markers are overlapping each other, try changing the coordinates of the second marker and check if it shows the second marker.

Comment: hehe... you were right.. thank you so much... I thought I've tested that...